# How to use print option C# selenium chrome driver

Tags: c#, selenium, pdf, selenium-chromedriver

In my sample web page, there have print option. I need to call that,

```
<a href="https://crim.brib.pk/RenderReport_Version2.aspx??Product_Id=MjgwMQ%3d%3d-J2XNpfmNU8Q%3d&amp;RUID=MTEwMDI0NTAwMTU%3d-rBg0P40kyho%3d&amp;FinalResult=T#" onclick="AlertandPrint();return false" class="three"><b> Print </b></a>
```

because I need to save above page as PDF(**My major requirement is to save that page in PDF format**). When I try to do it manually following popup window shows.

[image]

I need to do it through chrome C# selenium web driver. How can I do it? Please provide me sample code to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use send keys to CTRL+P on the webpage then use driver find element by and then click

Send keys documentation found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
//This should work for clicking the save/print button without seeing your code I cannot test it.
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="button-strip"]/button[1]")).Click();
```

Comment: Where did you get the _XPath_ as `"//*[@id="button-strip"]/button[1]"` ?

Comment: I just used the first button I could find on the web page I was using to illustrate the point. Just right click the print/save button and use inspect.

Answer (score 0):

The print window is os realted component and you cannot automate them with selenium itself. You may need additional library to automate that along with your selenium code.

You are two Nuget package to it. One simply use [InputSimulator](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/520/simulating-keypress-in-the-right-way-using-inputsimulator-with-csharp-in-winforms) and do key inputs like

Or

Automate browse window usings [AutoITX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoItX.Dotnet/) nuget package.